Convert video in 2 passes using technology dash/ffmpeg
ffmpeg -i /2160.mp4 -deadline best -speed 1
     -c:a libopus -b:a 128k -ar 48000
     -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 240
     -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0
     -filter:v:0 scale=-2:360,fps=30
     -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0
     -filter:v:1 scale=-2:480,fps=30
     -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$"
     -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$"
     -dash_segment_type webm
     -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -seg_duration 10
     -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a"
     -pass 1 -f dash null /dev/null &&
     ffmpeg -i /2160.mp4 -deadline best -speed 1
     -c:a libopus -b:a 128k -ar 48000
     -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 240
     -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0
     -filter:v:0 scale=-2:360,fps=30
     -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0
     -filter:v:1 scale=-2:480,fps=30
     -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$"
     -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$"
     -dash_segment_type webm
     -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -seg_duration 10
     -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a"
     -pass 2 -f dash /test1/dash.mpd

Years at the output we get one final file in the format .webm. Performing in two passes, this operation is not difficult. But what to do in my example, when I use segments and in general is it acceptable to perform the given example in 2 passes?
In this case I get an error
[AVFormatContext @ 0x563ad16700c0] Unable to choose an output format for '/dev/null'; use a standard extension for the filename or specify the format manually.
[out#1 @ 0x563ad166ff80] Error initializing the muxer for /dev/null: Invalid argument
Error opening output file /dev/null.
Error opening output files: Invalid argument

I would also like to clarify that I write before each video stream. -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0
I can't say for sure, in my example each video stream gets its own audio track? Or one for all? That is, why 2 audio tracks on 2 streams, if you can make one for two...
In general, the command that I gave as an example. Is it possible to make it simpler?

-f dash null /dev/null should be -f dash /dev/null
